# What is the position of the top of the axis label text in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, font-size, axes, axis-labels

I'm trying to position some additional annotations to line up with the axis label text in a matplotlib figure. How is this position calculated, as a function of the font size of the tick and axes labels, and the font size of the annotation?

Specifically, given a figure with a single set of tick labels and a single axis label along  the x-axis, with font sizes `tick_font_size` and `label_font_size` respectively, what is the vertical position `y` in figure points that would result in

```
ax.annotate('Some text', (x, y), va='top', ...)
```

placing `'Some text'` with font size `annotation_font_size`, in vertical alignment with the axis label?

---

For various reasons, I must use `annotate` for this, and `va='top'` is a constraint; and I need to use the font size information above — that is, I'm looking for the function of the form

```
y = f(tick_font_size, label_font_size, annotation_font_size)
```

with all values in figure points (i.e., usable with `textcoords='offset points'` in `annotate`). Such an algorithm must exist, since it is clearly used by `matplotlib` to position the axis label in the first place.

Comment: 'top' is not a valid option for ha

Answer (score 2):

Get the object returned when setting xlabel. Render the figure and use get_position to get the position of the label. From there do some transformations and add the annotation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2

xlabel = plt.xlabel("test")
plt.plot(x, y)

ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.draw(fig.canvas.get_renderer())

trans = xlabel.get_transform()
xpos, ypos = trans.transform(xlabel.get_position())  # convert to display coordinates
xpos, ypos = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform([xpos, ypos])  # convert to figure coordinates
ax.annotate('Some text', (xpos+0.05, ypos), xycoords='figure fraction', va="top")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Assume I've just got `ax`, with axes and labels already set up. How do I get `xlabel`?

Comment: ax.get_xaxis().get_label()

Comment: This is helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for. What I need is the function that maps `ax`, `tick_font_size`, `label_font_size` and    `annotation_font_size` to a value for `y` that aligns the annotation with the axis label. (That function exists, since its used by `matplotlib` to position the axis label.)